# Run interactive program from ssh then disconnect and reconnect

Tags: ssh, background-process

From my laptop I'd need to start a ssh terminal to a remote desktop in which I'll run a long running program testdisk or photorec, then once I setup my selections start the data recovery. Then I'd need a way to cleanly disconnect the ssh session before the laptop goes to sleep. I the morning I could reconnect the ssh session in which I'd recover the long run program still running or whatever status it is, normally terminated or prompting for any input.

Is there a way to do this please?
Many thanks

Comment: Look into the utility called `screen`.

Comment: Thanks muru, tmux is THE answer.